# content page auto resizing with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, web-applications

I'm using jquery mobile to build a web app. There are 3 divs among each other and again 2 divs in each of them. In the first one is an image with a width of 50% and autosized height. In the second one there is just text. I want this 3 divs among each other to fill the whole content page and resize to the different device sizes.
Right now, the content does not change the size and jquery adds them to a scroll view if the height of the view gets to small.
Here two screenshots for better understanding:

[image: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3565/jasgx2jj_png.htm]

[image: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3565/esxunsvv_png.htm]

thanks for any help

Comment: add you html and css to question. snapshots aren't enough.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using pixels, try using percentages in adjusting your height and width. Also, you can use auto to adjust the size in the entire screen by default regardless of the screen size of the device.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
<div class="group>
  <div class="img"><img src="path-to-img"/></div>
  <div class="text"> Text 1 </div>
</div>
<div class="group>
  <div class="img"><img src="path-to-img"/></div>
  <div class="text"> Text 2 </div>
</div>
<div class="group>
  <div class="img"><img src="path-to-img"/></div>
  <div class="text"> Text 3 </div>
</div>
```

--- stylesheet ---

```
.group{ width: 100%; }
.img, .text{ width: 50%; }
```

Hope this helps.